Unnecessary animation between two poses keyframed
when key framing 2 poses, unwanted poses get added in between, the legs get crossed when trying to animate it to walk


Welcome to BSE. I'm afraid we don't have nearly enough information to even guess what's happened there. I think we'll need to see your Blend file which you can share via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the full link into it.

(0) Make sure there are no extra keyframes created. (1) Check your rotation order. (2) Unroll rotations in the graph editor.
